# How to add dependencies to Rails engine's dummy app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile, gemfile.lock

I would like to add a few dependencies in my test/dummy app so that I can do integration test of my engine. I added a test/dummy/Gemfile and put the dependencies on it:

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_invitable'
```

after I run bundle install inside the test/dummy, the test/dummy/Gemfile.lock is created.

but when I run rails g devise:install inside the test/dummy, it says

```
method_missing': undefined method `active_storage' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00007fad8f2a0dc0> (NoMethodError)
```

How am I able to add dependencies to the dummy app?
The only way I can get it to work is if I add it to the dependencies of my engine gem. but I prefer not to do that

EDIT: I added rails in my Gemfile and devise install can be run, but after I run my test, it has this error:

```
test/dummy/config/initializers/devise.rb:11:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Devise (NameError)
```